# SimpleIOC with MVVMlight register and use

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm-light, service-locator, simpleioc

Hi i try to register my class into serviceLocator and reuse it my code is:

```
public ViewModelLocator()
{
    ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(() => SimpleIoc.Default);

    SimpleIoc.Default.Register<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>(true);

    SimpleIoc.Default.Register<MainViewModel>(() =>
    {
        return new MainViewModel(UnitOfWorkItem);
    });
    SimpleIoc.Default.Register<LoginViewModel>(() =>
    {
        return new LoginViewModel(UnitOfWorkItem);
    });
}

public UnitOfWork UnitOfWorkItem
{
    get
    {
        return ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<UnitOfWork>();
    }
}

public MainViewModel Main
{
    get
    {
        return ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<MainViewModel>();
    }
}
```

when i try to give UnitOfWorkItem into the function that instance MainViewModel throw a exception like:

> Type not found in cache: Client.Business.UnitOfWork.

my stack trace is:

> in GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Ioc.SimpleIoc.DoGetService(Type serviceType,
>   String key, Boolean cache) in
>   D:\GalaSoft\mydotnet\MVVMLight\source\GalaSoft.MvvmLight\GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Extras
>   (PCL)\Ioc\SimpleIoc.cs:riga 537    in
>   GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Ioc.SimpleIoc.GetInstanceTService in
>   D:\GalaSoft\mydotnet\MVVMLight\source\GalaSoft.MvvmLight\GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Extras
>   (PCL)\Ioc\SimpleIoc.cs:riga 912    in
>   PrivateVideoChat.Client.ViewModel.ViewModelLocator.get_UnitOfWorkItem()
>   in C:\Users\c.fasolin\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2013\Projects\PrivateVideoChat.Solution\PrivateVideoChat.Client\ViewModel\ViewModelLocator.cs:riga
>   63    in
>   PrivateVideoChat.Client.ViewModel.ViewModelLocator.<.ctor>b__0_1() in
>   C:\Users\c.fasolin\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2013\Projects\PrivateVideoChat.Solution\PrivateVideoChat.Client\ViewModel\ViewModelLocator.cs:riga
>   52

Where I am wrong
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `UnitOfWorkItem` property is looking for the registered `UnitOfWork`. But you never register anything with that class, you register the `IUnitOfWork`!

You need to fix your `UnitOfWorkItem` by changing `UnitOfWork` into `IUnitOfWork`:

```
public UnitOfWork UnitOfWorkItem
{
    get
    {
        return ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<IUnitOfWork>();
    }
}
```

**Even better:**

Just for your information, the power of an IoC container is that you can chain the registration. For example, in your case, your `LoginViewModel` and your `MainViewModel` require a `UnitOfWork` as constructor parameter.

If you register both `UnitOfWork`, `MainViewModel` and `LoginViewModel` like this:

```
SimpleIoc.Default.Register<UnitOfWork>(); 
SimpleIoc.Default.Register<LoginViewModel>(); 
SimpleIoc.Default.Register<MainViewModel>();
```

The container will automatically provide to the `ViewModels` constructor the registred `UnitOfWork` and so on.

This way you do not need to create a property getting the UnitOfWork for giving it to the LoginViewModel constructor.